# Selecting different columns from databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I have two databases and each has the same tables. For example I have table called `world` and it has 4 columns: `pkey1`, `pkey2`,`companyid`, `company_name`

I made a query which searches for rows which have the same pkey1 and pkey2 but one or many of their other property is different in the 2 tables. My question is how can I see only the different properties?

Here is my query it selects the rows which have the same pkey1 and pkey2 how can I upgrade it to see the columns where there is difference in both databases and of course if there is no difference the result of the query should return NULL in the column here is an example what I want to achieve:

in first database (1,1,345,'Ron'), second database (1,1,377,'Ron') the result should be (1,1,345,null)

Comment: "Here is my query" - no there is no query in your question. Edit your question and add the create table statements for all tables involved, the complete SQL query you are using, some sample data and the expected output. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Basically to reference data in a different database, you'll need a database link, since you are using PostgreSQL, this documentation should help;

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

You'll need to use this command to create the link (in this case with a name);

```
SELECT dblink_connect('CONNECTIONNAME', 'REMOTEDBCONNECTIONSTRING');
```

Then you can use this new connection via a select query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('CONNECTIONNAME','SELECT * FROM foo') AS t(a int, b text, c text[]);
```

And replace 'foo' with your 'world' table name, then change the AS into the variables that relate to pkey1, pkey2,companyid, company_name etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your databases are linked, you can join both tables and with "case" statement check if the value has changed:

```
select a.pkey1, a.pkey2, 
case when a.companyid <> b.companyid then a.companyid else null end as companyid, 
case when a.company_name <> b.company_name then a.company_name else null end as company_name
from db1.dbo.world a
inner join db2.dbo.world b on a.pkey1 = b.pkey1 and a.pkey2 = b.pkey2
```

If you want to omit rows with no difference you can use "except":

```
select a.pkey1, a.pkey2, 
case when a.companyid <> b.companyid then a.companyid else null end as companyid, 
case when a.company_name <> b.company_name then a.company_name else null end as company_name
from (
    select pkey1, pkey2, companyid, company_name 
    from db1.dbo.world
    except 
    select pkey1, pkey2, companyid, company_name 
    from db2.dbo.world) a
inner join db2.dbo.world b on a.pkey1 = b.pkey1 and a.pkey2 = b.pkey2
```

Comment: `db1.dbo.world` is invalid for Postgres

Comment: What do we do when we have 1 mil columns,case won't work ?